# jquery.lazyload.js plugin download

Tags: jquery-plugins

I am trying to download jquery.lazyload.js plugin, Please guide me from where I can download 
 this plugin? I am trying to implement lazyloading, and when I search online, I found that we need this plugin.

Comment: Have you tried its website? http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload

Comment: @PezCuckow Yes, but I didnt find any download option in the website.

Comment: Have you tried google: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=laxzyload+download

See: Download jQuery LazyLoad Ad - Web2ajaX

Comment: Or this: "Lazy loader is a jQuery plugin written in JavaScript. It delays loading of images ... Download: http://www.appelsiini.net/download/jquery.lazyload.pack.js "

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Copy of comments:

- Have you tried its website? appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload
- Have you tried google: [google.co.uk/search?q=laxzyload+download](http://google.co.uk/search?q=laxzyload%20download) See: Download jQuery LazyLoad Ad - Web2ajaX
  1
- Or this: "Lazy loader is a jQuery plugin written in JavaScript. It delays loading of images ... Download: [appelsiini.net/download/jquery.lazyload.pack.js](http://appelsiini.net/download/jquery.lazyload.pack.js) " – Pez Cuckow